# Grafico de arbol conexo en python 2,7

Tags: python-2.7, teoría-de-grafos

Buen dia a todos,

Estoy aprendiendo a realizar gráficos en Python 2.7, pero no tengo idea como graficar un arbol conexo en python intente realizarlo de la siguiente manera pero el resultado no es lo que esperaba.

Dataframe BORDE

```
Node1   Coord_X1    Coord_Y1    Node2   Coord_X2    Coord_Y2    distancia
185345.0    773597.6169 9962982.575 185346.0    773614.916  9963027.287 47.9418585885
185345.0    773597.6169 9962982.575 185347.0    773614.7503 9962997.751 22.8880836154
185345.0    773597.6169 9962982.575 186566.0    773613.8039 9963065.571 84.5597716719
185345.0    773597.6169 9962982.575 185351.0    773655.4929 9963006.051 62.4560161399
```

Dataframe NODO

```
    ID      Coord_X      Coord_Y
   186566  773613.8039  9963065.571
   185342  773555.1688  9963035.582
   189946  773634.7926  9963058.732
   185346  773614.9160  9963027.287
   189945  773583.1306  9963059.069
   189943  773517.5156  9963059.012
   189944  773552.3801  9963059.070
   185351  773655.4929  9963006.051
   185345  773597.6169  9962982.575
   186557  773553.1549  9963101.634
   185341  773554.5726  9962997.507
   185347  773614.7503  9962997.751
   185340  773551.2906  9962981.867
   185331  773475.4813  9962983.065

#-----------------------------------------

import itertools
import copy
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g1 = nx.Graph()

for i, elrow1 in BORDE.iterrows(): 

   g1.add_edge(elrow1[0], elrow1[3]) 

#BORDE un dataframe de nodos y distancias  entre nodos

for i, nlrow1 in NODO.iterrows(): 
    g1.node[nlrow1['ID']] = nlrow1[1:].to_dict() 

#NODO dataframe de nodos

#%%
print('# of edges: {}'.format(g1.number_of_edges()))
print('# of nodes: {}'.format(g1.number_of_nodes()))
#%%
node_positions1 = {node[0]: (node[1]['Coord_X'], -node[1]['Coord_Y']) for node in g1.nodes(data=True)}
dict(list(node_positions1.items())[0:7])

    #%%
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6)) 

    nx.draw(g1, pos=node_positions1, edge_color='blue', node_size=15, node_color='black')

    plt.title('Grafico de todos los caminos', size=15)

    plt.show()
```

￼[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento obtener un gráfico asi,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Conociendo la matriz de adyacencia.

Gracias por su colaboración.

Saludos

Comment: import networkx as nx
N1 = [185345.0,185345.0,185345.0,185345.0] # nodo 1
N2 = [185346.0,185347.0 ,186566.0,185351.0] # nodo 2
dis = [47.9418585885,22.8880836154,84.5597716719,62.4560161399] # distancia
N =[185345.0,185345.0,185345.0,185345.0,185346.0,185347.0 ,186566.0,185351.0] # nodos

Comment: g = nx.Graph()

g.add_nodes_from(N)

Borde = zip(N1,N2)

g.add_edges_from(Borde)

peso = zip(N1,N2,dis)

g.add_weighted_edges_from(peso)

Comment: g.edges(data = True)

nx.draw_networkx(g)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx

N1 = [185345.0,185345.0,185345.0,185345.0] # nodo 1
N2 = [185346.0,185347.0 ,186566.0,185351.0] # nodo 2
dis = [47.9418585885,22.8880836154,84.5597716719,62.4560161399] # distancia
N =[185345.0,185345.0,185345.0,185345.0,185346.0,185347.0 ,186566.0,185351.0] # nodos
#%%
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(N)
Borde = zip(N1,N2)
g.add_edges_from(Borde)
peso = zip(N1,N2,dis)
g.add_weighted_edges_from(peso)
#%%
g.edges(data = True)
nx.draw_networkx(g)
```

> respuesta Out:  [(185345.0, 185346.0, {'weight': 47.9418585885}), 
>   (185345.0, 185347.0, {'weight': 22.8880836154}),  (185345.0, 186566.0,
>   {'weight': 84.5597716719}),  (185345.0, 185351.0, {'weight':
>   62.4560161399})]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]